# Make a call to katex to render LaTeX from Org to HTML

Tags: org-mode, org-export

This would allow the resulting HTML buffer to be viewed in `eww`, then allowing `org-preview-html` to work with LaTeX equations.

Any inline LaTeX equations in the Org document (`$eq$` and etc) can be passed in the stdin of `katex`, and multiline/"display style" equations (`\[ eq \]` and etc) are passed to the stdin of `katex -d`.

Is there a way to override the LaTeX ⇒ HTML transformation that will let me do this?

Comment: (This should be a comment, but my reputation is insufficient...) Related things I've found: - To my understanding, this seems somewhat like what you want, only with XWidget: https://github.com/fuxialexander/emacs-webkit-katex-render - Overriding MathJax in favor of KaTeX in HTML output: https://amitp.blogspot.com/2019/02/emacs-org-mode-and-katex.html But KaTeX doesn't implement all of the LaTeX features MathJaX does, so be carefull with this one.

Comment: You can use [texfrag](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/texfrag) as an alternative. It uses LaTeX to render those fragments as png.